# Installing ownCloud with NGINX and SQLite

Tags: debian, webserver, sqlite

I have a distro based on Debian Jessie running on an ARM device.

How can I install a simple, secure ownCloud 8.2.2 installation that uses NGINX and SQLite without installing Apache and MySQL?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The default dependencies of the `owncloud` package in Debian include the php mysql binding and apache, but there are alternatives for sqlite and other webservers.

If you do:

```
apt install owncloud php5-sqlite nginx apache2-
```

then apt will notice you're installing the `nginx` and `php5-sqlite` package, decide that those satisfy the dependencies of the `owncloud` package, and not pull in mysql or apache2.
Unfortunately, something does indeed still pull in apache, so we add an explicit instruction to apt that it should not do that, with the `apache2-` bit. Notice the dash ("-") at the end; that tells apt to remove a package, or to not install it if it hasn't been installed yet.

Alternatively, you can also install the `nginx` and `php5-sqlite` first, configure them (if needed), and only *then* (after you've brought those up) install the `owncloud` package.

Comment: When running this command I am, of course, asked whether I want to continue. Looking at the list of extra packages to be installed reveals `apache2`, `apache2-bin`, `apache2-data`, etc. So does this command install Apache, because I don't want this to happen?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've updated my post to incorporate that.

Answer (score 0):

Owncloud is providing an own documentation for manual installations it works fine with Debian and i have never problems installing it... work with the requirements, and then start an manual installation ;)

https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.2/admin_manual/installation/index.html

Comment: Thanks for this. These instructions seem more targeted at Apache. Will they still be applicable for NGINX and, if so, what should the NGINX config be?

Comment: The nginx conf is there https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.2/admin_manual/installation/nginx_configuration.html